# How do I set an opened form to read only in access vba?

Tags: ms-access, vba

How do I set a form in access vba editor to read only after writing a command to open it?  I've entered the code below.  The commented section highlights where I thought that the code might go.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command10_Click()

Dim DBS As Database

Dim rstUserPwd As Recordset

Dim bFoundMatch As Boolean

Dim txtUsername As String

Dim txtPassword As String

Dim FRM As Form

Set DBS = CurrentDb

Set rstUserPwd = DBS.OpenRecordset("qryUserPwd")


bFoundMatch = False


If rstUserPwd.RecordCount > 0 Then

rstUserPwd.MoveFirst


Do While rstUserPwd.EOF = False


If rstUserPwd![Username] = Form_frmLogin.txtUsername.Value And rstUserPwd![Password] = Form_frmLogin.txtPassword.Value Then


bFoundMatch = True


Exit Do

End If

rstUserPwd.MoveNext

Loop

End If


If bFoundMatch = True Then GoTo G1

On Error GoTo G2


G1: If rstUserPwd![Username] = "wsmith" Then

MsgBox "Access Granted"

DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

DoCmd.OpenForm "AmalgamatedForm"

DoCmd.OpenForm "AgeUKRequirementsForm"

DoCmd.OpenForm "CiberRequirementsForm"

DoCmd.OpenForm "Blackbaud_ITT_ResponseForm"

DoCmd.OpenForm "Ciber_ITT_ResponseForm"

DoCmd.OpenForm "ThankQ_ITT_ResponseForm"


ElseIf rstUserPwd![Username] = "admin" Then

MsgBox "Access Granted"

DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

DoCmd.OpenForm "AmalgamatedForm"

DoCmd.OpenForm "AgeUKRequirementsForm"

DoCmd.OpenForm "CiberRequirementsForm"

DoCmd.OpenForm "Blackbaud_ITT_ResponseForm"

DoCmd.OpenForm "Ciber_ITT_ResponseForm"

DoCmd.OpenForm "ThankQ_ITT_ResponseForm"


ElseIf rstUserPwd![Username] = "ageuk" Then

MsgBox "Access Granted"

DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

DoCmd.OpenForm "AmalgamatedForm"

'how do i set the form in row above to read only here until exit database

DoCmd.OpenForm "AgeUKRequirementsForm"

'how do i set the form in row above to read only here until exit database

DoCmd.OpenForm "CiberRequirementsForm"

'how do i set the form in row above to read only here until exit database

DoCmd.OpenForm "Blackbaud_ITT_ResponseForm"

'how do i set the form in row above to read only here until exit database

DoCmd.OpenForm "Ciber_ITT_ResponseForm"

'how do i set the form in row above to read only here until exit database

DoCmd.OpenForm "ThankQ_ITT_ResponseForm"

'how do i set the form in row above to read only here until exit database


ElseIf rstUserPwd![Username] = "ciber" Then

MsgBox "Access Granted"

DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

DoCmd.OpenForm "AmalgamatedForm"

'how do i set the form in row above to read only here until exit database

DoCmd.OpenForm "AgeUKRequirementsForm"

'how do i set the form in row above to read only here until exit database

DoCmd.OpenForm "CiberRequirementsForm"

'how do i set the form in row above to read only here until exit database

DoCmd.OpenForm "Ciber_ITT_ResponseForm"

'how do i set the form in row above to read only here until exit database


Else


G2: MsgBox "Incorrect username or password"


End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the *DataMode* option to open a form read-only.

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "Ciber_ITT_ResponseForm", DataMode:=acFormReadOnly
```